# How do you sum different columns of binary variables based on a desired set of variables/column?

Tags: r

I used the code below for a total of 25 variables and it  worked.It shows up as either 1 or 0:

```
jb$finances <- ifelse(grepl("Finances", jb$content.roll),1,0)
```

I want to be able to add the number of "1" s in each row across the multiple of selected column/variables I just made (using the code above) into another column called "sum.content". I used the code below:

```
jb <- jb %>%
mutate(sum.content=sum(jb$Finances,jb$Exercise,jb$Volunteer,jb$Relationships,jb$Laugh,jb$Gratitude,jb$Regrets,jb$Meditate,jb$Clutter))
```

I didn't get an error using the code above, but I did not get the outcome I wanted.

The result of this was 14 for all my row.I was expecting something <9 since I only selected for 9 variables.I don't want to delete the other variables like V1 and V2, I just want to focus on summing some variables.

This is what I got using the code:

```
    V1  V2... Finances Exercise Volunteer Relationships Laugh sum.content
1               1        1        1          1            0    14
2               0        1        0          0            1    14
2               0        0        0          0            1    14
```

This is What I want:

```
    V1  V2... Finances Exercise Volunteer Relationships Laugh sum.content
1               1        1        1          1            0       4
2               0        1        0          0            1       1
2               0        0        0          0            1       1
```

I want R to add the number of 1's in each row(within the columns I want to select). How would I go about incorporating the adding of the 1's in code(from a set of variable/column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer that uses `dplyr` to sum across rows of variables starting with the letter `V`. We'll simulate some data, convert to binary, and then sum the rows.

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(100,100,30),nrow = 10)
# recode to binary
data <- apply(data,2,function(x){x <- ifelse(x > 100,1,0)})
# change some of the column names to illustrate impact of
# select() within mutate()
colnames(data) <- c(paste0("V",1:5),paste0("X",1:5))

as.data.frame(data) %>% 
     mutate(total = select(.,starts_with("V")) %>% rowSums)
```

...and the output, where the sums should equal the sum of V1 - V5 but not
X1 - X5:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 total
1   1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0     2
2   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0     2
3   1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0     4
4   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0     2
5   0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0     2
6   0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1     3
7   1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1     3
8   1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1     3
9   1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0     3
10  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0     3
>
```

Comment: It ended up selecting only the variables I mention such that all the other variables got deleted. I am not interested in deleting the other variable, I am looking to sum the binary values in just a view variables while keeping all the variables.

Comment: Yes, but with bind_cols() you can merge the result with the original data. Will update my answer later when I am at my computer again...

Comment: @Ani - If we move the `select()` inside `mutate()`, the original data remains in the output data frame, per my updated answer. We could also do this with `bind_cols()`, but this approach requires fewer passes of the data.